# In redis sorted set how get score value by key name

Tags: redis

In Redis-cli I added two records in ordered set,

but my problem is how I can access the score value of article:votes by key value article:463? i try this: `ZRANGE article:votes 0 -1 withscores` this gives me all sorted set keys with scores, but if I have 2000 items in this sorted set how I get a score fast?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don`t know how to write this code or find the code, my main problem is this.
How to write redis code in a sorted set, to find score by key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll want to use the `ZSCORE` command (https://redis.io/commands/zscore/).

Example... first add some values to a sorted set:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd article:votes 12 article:123 13 article:124 99 article:125
(integer) 3
```

`ZSCORE` has O(1) performance so performance won't degrade as your sorted set gets bigger.

Now, what score does `article:123` have?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zscore article:votes article:123
"12"
```